# Map observable list to another typ of observable list in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this observable list `Observable<Person[]> persons`
Which has following attributes

```
    Person{
id: string,
name: string
}
```

I want to map it to this type of Observable list  `Observable<Cars[]> cars`

```
Car{
refId: string,
lable: string
}
```

Comment: We’d need to know how you want to map the data but you’ll likely be combining the map pipeable operator and the array map `obs$.pipe(map(arr => arr.map(item => { … return newItem }))`

Comment: Can u please apply it to my example.

Comment: Like I said, would need minimal example. I don’t know how you want to map the data